# logitech ghub autoclicker lua fix

Tags: lua, logitech

can anybody fix this logitech ghub autoclicker? i want the script to turn on/off when the back button is pressed, and when pressed once while holding the left mouse button, it clicks all the time until the button is released

```
local counter = 0
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
        counter = counter+1
        if counter % 2 == 1 then
            clickingEnabled = true
        else
            clickingEnabled = false
        end
    end
    while clickingEnabled and IsMouseButtonPressed(1) do
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(10)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(10)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the game, in the "Controls Settings", introduce alternative key for "Shoot" action.
   For example, let it be keyboard key <kbd>P</kbd>.
   So, now in the game you can shoot either using Left Mouse Button or using Keyboard key <kbd>P</kbd>.
   Of course, you will use LMB for manual shooting as usually, but your GHub script will use <kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Make sure:

   - you can shoot with Left Mouse Button (as usual);
   - you can shoot with key <kbd>P</kbd>;
   - you can shoot with key <kbd>P</kbd> while Left Mouse Button is pressed;
3. Set the script:

```
local is_active

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
      is_active = not is_active
   elseif is_active and event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      while 
         PressKey("P")
         Sleep(10)
         ReleaseKey("P")
         Sleep(10)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
   end
end
```

---

**Method #2**
If your game lacks ability to set an alternative key.

1. Make sure mouse button 5 is ignored by the game.
   The game must do nothing when you press it while playing.
2. In GHub, assign "Left click" action to some mouse button you usually never use.
   For example, button #8.
   This way MB8 will act as a spare Left Click, just in case something wrong happen with your LMB (if script goes wrong for some reason).
3. Set the script.

```
local is_active

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
      is_active = not is_active
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      PressMouseButton(1)
      if is_active then
         repeat
            Sleep(10)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(10)
            PressMouseButton(1)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) 
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   end
end
```

4. In GHub, assign "Forward" action to physical LMB. ("Forward" is the default action for mouse button 5).  Probably GHub will ask you "are you sure", say "yes".

Comment: is it one and only way to do this, because in my game there is no alternative keys

Comment: @zeush - Answer updated.